I am looking for the sample payload of the Teams room device for the below API call
I am looking for the payload of the below API call.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/<CallerId>?$expand=sessions($expand=segments)
I am looking for the details of the teams room and how does it look in the payload
I have tried the API call, since I do not have any teams room devices involved, I did not see anything about it in my response. Hoping that the sample payload may have something like the below:
"startDateTime": "2024-12-13T15:00:00Z",
    "endDateTime": "2024-12-13T16:00:00Z",
    "sessions": [
        {
            "id": "session1",
            "startDateTime": "2024-12-13T15:05:00Z",
            "endDateTime": "2024-12-13T15:35:00Z",
            "caller": {
                "name": "Conference Room A",
                "identity": {
                    "device": {
                        "id": "device-123",
                        "displayName": "Conference Room A"
                    }
                },
                "userAgent": {
                    "headerValue": "Microsoft Teams Rooms (v4.16.40.0)",
                    "platform": "windows",
                    "productFamily": "teams"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "session2",
            "startDateTime": "2024-12-13T15:10:00Z",
            "endDateTime": "2024-12-13T15:50:00Z",
            "caller": {
                "name": "John Doe's Laptop",
                "identity": {
                    "user": {
                        "id": "user-456",
                        "displayName": "John Doe"
                    }
                },
                "userAgent": {
                    "headerValue": "Microsoft Teams (v1.5.0)",
                    "platform": "macOS",
                    "productFamily": "teams"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


That's about right as far as structure goes. Just a few notes:

The "name" attribute is the hostname of the device, so depending on how the device is configured it may not exactly match the displayName.
The "platform" attribute will have a value of "RoomSystem" to indicate the endpoint is a Teams Rooms device, as it usually won't be obvious based on the headerValue.
Right now, rooms devices have an identity type of "user," not "device."

Below is an example:
"sessions": [
    {
      "id": "session-id",
      "modalities": [
        "audio",
        "video",
        "videoBasedScreenSharing"
      ],
      "startDateTime": "2024-12-19T18:08:53.4589638Z",
      "endDateTime": "2024-12-19T18:12:38.428232Z",
      "isTest": false,
      "caller": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.participantEndpoint",
        "name": "AB123CD-MTR",
        "userAgent": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
          "headerValue": "CallSignalingAgent (51/24241.400.3089.3663/24111108100;release_bp/revert_shell_sharing_change.2024.30.01.19;releases/CL2024.R30)"
          "platform": "RoomSystem",
          "productFamily": "teams"
        },
        "associatedIdentity": {
          "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.userIdentity",
          "id": "user-id",
          "displayName": "Conference Room 1",
          "tenantId": "my-tenant-id",
          "userPrincipalName": "AB123CD@my-tenant.com"
        },
        "feedback": {
          "rating": "excellent"
        }
      },

